# Qual é a finalidade do terceiro parâmetro de AddEventListener?

Tags: javascript

Quando quero adicionar um `listener` de algum evento em Javascript uso o `addEventListener`.

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      alert('clicked');
})
```

Porém percebi que, em alguns códigos, usa-se um terceiro parâmetro, que creio ser um `Boolean`. Mais ou menos assim:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      alert('clicked');
}, false)
```

Li a [documentação do Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener) para ver do que se tratava, mas acabei ficando mais confuso com a explicação.

Alguém podem me esclarecer com alguma exemplo para que serve esse terceiro parâmetro de `addEventListener`?

Comment: Wallace: A resposta era o que procuravas?

Comment: @Sergio eu costumo demorar um pouquinho para marcar elas. Obrigado por me lembrar (sem querer abusar, acho que sempre precisará me avisar)

Comment: Fazes bem em esperar, neste caso fiquei só curioso se faltava algo.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

O terceiro parâmetro chama-se `capture` e define se o `addEventListener` deve responder a eventos que descem no DOM, ou sobem no DOM.

Basicamente o evento percorre dois caminhos quando acontece. Se clicares num elemento por exemplo, primeiro serão chamados os `addEventListener` que tiverem `true` no terceiro argumento, de cima para baixo no DOM. Depois serão chamados os `addEventListener` que tiverem `false` (ou nada)  no terceiro argumento, de baixo para cima no DOM. O evento percorre sempre dois caminhos (se não for parado). Começa no `document` desce de elemento em elemento até encontrar o alvo, e depois percorre o mesmo caminho de volta.

Essas duas fases são chamadas ***capture phase*** e ***bubling phase***, respetivamente fase de captura e fase de ascenção. O sitio onde muda é o `event.target`, ou seja quando a phase de captura encontrar o elemento que originou o evento. O que distingue em que fase o `addEventListener` é accionado é esse terceiro argumento `capture`.

Um exemplo prático seria:

```js
function logCaptura(e) {
    console.log(this.tagName, 'fase de captura');
}

function logBubble(e) {
    console.log(this.tagName, 'fase de bubling');
}


document.querySelector('section').addEventListener('click', logCaptura, true);
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', logCaptura, true);
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', logCaptura, true);

document.querySelector('section').addEventListener('click', logBubble);
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', logBubble);
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', logBubble);
```

```html
<section>
    <div>
        <button type="button">Clica-me!</button>
    </div>
</section>
```

Os auscultadores de eventos são disparados de cima para baixo no DOM e depois de baixo para cima. E neste exemplo é [irrelevante a ordem](https://jsfiddle.net/kqLkdk3c/1/) em que forem adicionados.

Esse argumento é útil para termos a certeza que apanhamos um evento "em primeira mão" e a tempo de impedir a sua propagação no DOM. Repara na diferênça nesta versão com um `e.stopPropagation();`: https://jsfiddle.net/kqLkdk3c/

Neste caso do exemplos auscultadores de eventos **sem** o capture `true` não chegam sequer a ser chamados.

**Mais informação [na MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)**

Comment: +1. Gostei da explicação.

Comment: É sempre bom auscultar suas explicações :)

Answer (score 0):

Só para complementar com um exemplo prático e didático, o **3º** parâmetro do método **addEventListener** é opcional e recebe um valor booleano que no caso for **`false (ou não conter os parâmetros)`** os eventos ocorreram na ordem do elemento filho para o elemento pai, ou seja, fase **bubling**:

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  alert('Primeiro o clique do botão');
}, false);

document.getElementById('div').addEventListener('click', () => {
  alert('Depois da div');
}, false);
```

```css
div {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
}

button {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
  <h2>Bubbling (dentro para fora)</h2>
  <button id="btn">Botão</button>
</div>
```

Caso o parâmetro seja **`true`** os eventos ocorreram na ordem do elemento pai para o elemento filho, ou seja, fase **capturing**:

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  alert('Depois do botão');
}, true);

document.getElementById('div').addEventListener('click', () => {
  alert('Primeiro o clique da div');
}, true);
```

```css
div {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
}

button {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
  <h2>Capturing (fora para dentro)</h2>
  <button id="btn">Botão</button>
</div>
```