# Eventos bubbles JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

O que significa um Evento Bubble em JavaScript?

Não consegui entender o significado e uso dos eventos Bubbles. 
Seguindo a referência do W3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_bubbles.asp

Poderiam por favor, ajudar nesta referência?

Comment: Acho que [esta outra pergunta/resposta (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/149663/129)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/149663/129) já abrange a tua pergunta:  Podes dar uma olhada?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Resumo:** `bubbles` é uma propriedade de alguns eventos e indica se o evento pode ser capturado fora do elemento onde foi criado, ou não.

**Explicação alongada:**

Por exemplo quando clica-mos num botão, podemos capturar o evento `click`. Esse é um evento que tem a propriedade `bubbles` e com valor `true`. Isso quer dizer que pode ser capturado ou interceptado em qualquer elemento pai desse mesmo.

Um exemplo:

```js
$('div').on('click', function(e) {
  console.log('O evento passou por', this.id, e.bubbles);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pai">
  <div id="filho">
    <div id="neto">
      <button>Clica-me</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Clicando no botão vê-mos que o evento passa pelos 3 elementos. Ora o mesmo não acontece por exemplo no evento `focus`.

Exemplo:

```js
$('div, input').on('focus', function(e) {
  console.log('O evento passou por', this.id, e.bubbles);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pai">
  <div id="filho">
    <div id="neto">
      <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="clica aqui"></input>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Isso porque o evento `focus` tem valor `false` na propriedade `bubbles`.

Para impedir essa propagação (*"bubbling"*)  podemos usar o `.stopPropagation();` que aplicado ao primeiro exemplo seria assim:

```js
$('div').on('click', function(e) {
  console.log('O evento passou por', this.id);
  // com esta condição, o evento não chega a "pai"
  if (this.id == 'filho') e.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pai">
  <div id="filho">
    <div id="neto">
      <button>Clica-me</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

É um conceito bem simples, às vezes a forma que é apresentado deixa um pouco confuso, mas basicamente um evento **`.bubbles`** retorna um valor booleano indicando se determinado evento é "borbulhante". O termo "borbulhar" vem da ideia de uma bolha de água que sobe, ou seja, o evento é primeiro capturado no elemento mais interno e depois propagado para elementos externos.

Segue uma ilustração apresentada no [quirksmode - ordem de eventos](https://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)

```
               / \
---------------| |-----------------
| elemento1    | |                |
|   -----------| |-----------     |
|   |elemento2 | |          |     |
|   -------------------------     |
|        Evento BUBBLING          |
-----------------------------------
```

E um exemplo que mostra na prática a ordem da propagação:

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

function bubble() {
  log('bubble: ' + this.firstChild.nodeValue.trim())
}

for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  divs[i].addEventListener('click', bubble, false);
}

var $log = $('#log');

function log(msg) {
  $log.append('<p>' + msg + '</p>');
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  min-height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>elemento 1
  <div>elemento 2
    <div>elemento 3
      <div>elemento 4
        <div>elemento 5</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<section id="log"></section>
```

Comment: +1, gostei da referência old school pro quirksmode

Comment: @bfavaretto "for all your browser quirks" hehe, nem eu sabia que era tão old.