# JS - Como pegar a selector do Elemento ou a árvore dele?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Olá,

Eu estou tentando fazer uma função que ao clicar em um elemento eu consiga pegar ou a arvore(todos os parents) do elemento (até o body ou uma tag específica), ou pegue algo parecido com o "Copy -> Copy Selector" do DevTools.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por exemplo quando eu clicar no `b` me retornar algo como `div > nav > h3 > b`.

Clicando no `label` retornar `div > label`.

Clicando no `h3` retornar `div > nav > h3`.

Podendo incluir o body se quiser... Caso precise inserir um id em um elemento para saber onde parar é uma solução viável também.

Agradeço desde já!

### Edit

Melhorando a dúvida...

Vamos supor que eu tenha uma estrutura HTML dentro de uma div.

Como por exemplo:

```
<div id="stack-ex">
     <div>
         <nav>
              <label>Teste</label>
         </nav>
         <label>Texto 2</label>
     </div>
</div>
```

Eu preciso listar o conteúdo do `#stack-ex` mais ou menos assim:

- div

  - nav

    - label
  - label

Então a estrutura do `<li>` é uma referencia ao conteúdo do `#stack-ex`, eu posteriormente precisaria junto com a lista ter a o `selector` do elemento que o item da lista faz referencia. Pois depois vou colocar algo como um botão para alterar cor, ou outros casos.

Por isso ao clicar precisaria pegar o `parent` dele pois depois só usaria `$(aqui)` sendo `aqui = #stack-ex > div > nav > label`.

O click era apenas algo para exemplificar para vocês me ajudarem com um exemplo prático, não necessariamente vou clicar e chamar a função.

Comment: Renan, você precisa só do nome das tags ? ou do objeto HTML em sí?

Comment: Basicamente a string mesmo.

Comment: Realmente eu não consegui entender bem o propósito. Vai até me desculpando, mas não entendi mesmo. Acho que seria interessante a gente conversar num chat para vc me explicar melhor isso e qual o objetivo, até porque estou achando estranho pegar a árvore toda do elemento. Acredito que deva ter uma solução melhor e mais simples. Fico no aguardo.

Comment: Olá, podemos conversar sim num chat, como podemos fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

Com jQuery você consegue retornar a árvore assim.

```
$('.evento').on('click', function () {
  $(this).parentsUntil('div.root');
  // ele não retornará o elemento atual clicado
  // então você pode pegar ele com o $(this) mesmo
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar um evento click para todos os elementos do `body` e tratar o clique no elemento clicado, buscando os seus ancestrais. No final irá retornar uma string no formato que pediu (demais explicações no código):

```js
$("body *").click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();          // evita o bubbling
   var ateh = "#corpo";          // seletor que define até onde irá procurar o ancestral
                                 // pode ser um id, class, tag ou outro seletor válido
   var prev = $(this)            // pega o elemento clicado
   .parentsUntil(ateh)           // pega os ancestrais até o primeiro filho definido na variável ateh
   .addBack();                   // adiciona o elemento clicado (jQuery v1.8 ou maior)
//   .andSelf();                 // adiciona o elemento clicado (jQuery v1.7 ou menor)
   var tags = prev.get()         // pega os elementos do nodelist
   .map(function(a){             // e converte em uma array com os objetos HTML
      return a.tagName           // retorna os nomes das tags do objetos HTML
   })
   .join(" > ")                  // converte em string separando-os por " > "
   .toLowerCase();               // converte tudo em minúsculas
   var pais = ateh               // monta a string final incluindo o ancestral definido
   + " > "                       // na variável ateh que não foi incluído no .parentsUntil()
   + tags;

   console.clear();              // limpa o console
   console.log(pais);            // imprime no console
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body id="corpo">
<div>
   div
   <nav>
      nav
      <h3>
         H3
         <b>
            b
         </b>
      </h3>
   </nav>
   <label>
      label
   </label>
</div>
</body>
```

**Uma observação a respeito do *bubbling*:**

Como um elemento está dentro de outro (é um descendente direto ou não), se você clicar nele estará clicando nos seus pais também. Ou seja, o evento será disparado no elemento clicado e em todos os seus ancestrais, mas o que queremos é que o evento escute apenas o elemento clicado. O `.stopPropagation()` serve justamente para isso, evitar que o evento seja disparado também pelos ancestrais do elemento clicado. Tem um bom **[tópico aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/200402/8063)** que trata do assunto.

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação, me ajudou mesmo!

Comment: Vamos falar por aqui rs

Comment: cara, continuo sem entender direito. É preciso um exemplo da estrutura do HTML e o que vc quer de resultado.

Comment: Vou explicar do inicio o problema.
Eu estou pegando o HTML dentro de uma DIV e estou mostrando como lista

Então algo como:

<div>

 <nav>
 
  <label> Texto </label>
 
 </nav>

 <label> Texto 2 </label>

</div>


É listado como:

-div
    > nav
         * label

    > label


Eu queria que ao clicar em um item de uma lista (que diz respeito ao HTML acima), 
me retorne a árvore dele. Para eu usar depois no Jquery como selector $(aqui). 
E assim conseguir referenciar o elemento posteriormente.

Comment: Poxa, a estrutura da lista ficou na mesma linha aqui nos comentarios.  Mas espero que entenda.

Comment: Então mas eu preciso desses elementos listados em outro lugar e a referencia deles.. Para alterar alguns atributos dele. Display, cor, etc... E tem que ser dinamico para qualquer pagina.

Comment: Se puder montar um exemplo, talvez ajude rsrs

Comment: Vou fazer o seguinte, vou responder aqui fora dos comentários, pois da pra usar HTML e estruturar melhor a dúvida. Vou responder aqui mesmo.

Comment: Respondi aqui em baixo... rs