# Botão onClick não responde

Tags: javascript

Olá, estou começando a estudar JS, resolvi fazer essa simples página testando algumas funcionalidades, mas não estou entendendo o porque do botão "Alerta!" não estar retornando o alert('Botao clicado');
desde já agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Curso de JS


    
      
      Alerta!

```
<script>
    var btnElement = document.querySelector('button.botao');

    btnElement.onClick = function() {
       alert('Botao clicado');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: coloca um return antes do alert que irá funcionar

Comment: https://braziljs.github.io/eloquente-javascript/chapters/manipulando-eventos/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo a resposta do @Rafael Costa "Vc tem que usar um addEventListener pra monitorar o evento de click no botão, nele vc passa o tipo de evento e a função que é chamada".

---

**addEventListener(evento, funçao[, opcional]);**

O primeiro parâmetro é o tipo do evento (como " click" ou " mousedown" ou qualquer outro evento HTML DOM .)

O segundo parâmetro é a função que queremos chamar quando o evento ocorrer.

O  [terceiro parâmetro é opcional e está bem explicado nesse link.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/149661/qual-%C3%A9-a-finalidade-do-terceiro-par%C3%A2metro-de-addeventlistener)

Observe que você não usa o prefixo "`on`" para o evento; use "`click`" em vez de " `onclick`".

```js
document.querySelector('button.botao').addEventListener("click", MarcusVinicius);

function MarcusVinicius() {
  alert("Botao clicado exemplo 1");
}
```

```html
<button class="botao">Click me</button>
```

**Segundo exemplo**

```js
var btnElement = document.querySelector('button.botao');
                                    
btnElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert('Botao clicado exemplo 2');
});
```

```html
<button class="botao">Click me</button>
```

**Terceiro exemplo**

```js
var btnElement= document.querySelector("button.botao"); // Acessando o botão // 
btnElement.addEventListener("click", MarcusVinicius); //chamando a função MarcusVinicius quando o evento click ocorrer //

function MarcusVinicius(){ 
alert('Botao do terceiro exemplo clicado');
};
```

```html
<button class="botao">Click me</button>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mto Obrigado! por certo o curso que eu tva vendo ta desatualizado, sla, vlww ai mano.

Answer (score 1):

Vc tem que usar um addEventListener pra monitorar o evento de click no botão, nele vc passa o tipo de evento e a função que é chamada